# How take from string the words I need?

Tags: python-3.x, string

I have many strings like these.

```
Roliffe (Day) - Thursday, 15 June 2019
Tadcorp Pk Munangle (Day) - Tuesday, 10 July 2019
Gecester Park (Night) - Friday, 26 June 2019
```

I need to take names for example Roliffe, Tadcorp Pk Munangle, Gecester Park

And dates 15 June 2019, 10 July 2019, 26 June 2019

How can I make it?

Comment: What have you tried to extract this data?

Comment: @paskh Does all the data follow the same pattern?

Comment: I tried to split with whitespaces, take last three items from the list for date and take everything behind (Day) or (Night), but I need more efficient way to do it

Comment: Yes all the data is in the same pattern

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use regular expressions like this:

```py
import re

string = """Roliffe (Day) - Thursday, 15 June 2019
Tadcorp Pk Munangle (Day) - Tuesday, 10 July 2019
Gecester Park (Night) - Friday, 26 June 2019"""

places = re.findall(r'([\w ]*) \(.*\)', string)
dates = re.findall(r'\d{2} \w* \d{4}', string)

print(', '.join(places))
print(', '.join(dates))
```

**Output**

```
Roliffe, Tadcorp Pk Munangle, Gecester Park
15 June 2019, 10 July 2019, 26 June 2019
```

Answer (score 1):

If the data follows the same pattern.
This will not be an efficient one but will work.

```
s = 'Roliffe (Day) - Thursday, 15 June 2019';
firstSplit = s.split('(');
name = firstSplit[0].trim();
date = firstSplit[1].split(',')[1].trim();
```